# "I or X is" vs. "I or X am"

Tags: conjugations

I'd like  to write something like:

> This is uncommonly lengthy so perhaps **I or the quote is** incorrect.

Is it correct to write *is* even though  the subject includes I? If not, what's the proper way to write it?

Comment: Would you write 'I is incorrect'?

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey no, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a good solution without rephrasing.  However, I suspect that this is not a likely problem.

You could treat "or the quote" as parenthetical:

> Perhaps I (or the quote) am incorrect.

This isn't particularly natural, I only mention it as it requires minimal rephrasing.

If you wanted to mention both, it would be much better to split.  I think the fact that "I" and "the quote" are so different (one is a person, one is a piece of writing) a native speaker wouldn't naturally coordinate them. So a natural expression might be

> Perhaps I'm incorrect, or perhaps the quote is.

You could rephrase to make the error the subject:

> Perhaps the error lies with me or the quote.

You can use a dummy subject

> Perhaps it's me or the quote that is incorrect.

There are lots of ways to avoid the problem.